# perl timegm() error inside unix shell script

Tags: perl

I am trying to run perl script inside a unix script. But while executing it I am getting an error.It works fine without timegm() perl  function. Here is the code and the error message.

#!/bin/ksh

```
    echo "I M IN KSH"
    i=10
    echo "value of i in ksh is $i"
    perl << _MYCODE_

    print "I M IN PERL\n";
    use Time::Local;

    my \$i = $i;    
    print "Value of i in perl $i\n";    
    $time_epoo = timegm(13,06,22,29,2,2016-1900);     

    print "$time_epoo"

    _MYCODE_   

    echo "BACK IN KSH"

------------------------OUTPUT WITH ERROR--------------
I M IN KSH
value of i in ksh is 10
syntax error at - line 7, near "="
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
BACK IN KSH
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't really know ksh interpolation rules, but I'm guessing the first $ in  "my \$i = $i" is escaped to prevent ksh from interpolating it. If this is the case, why isn't the $ in  "$time_epo = ..."  escaped too?  I think mkHun's answer will remove any potential ambiguity in variable interpolation and fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

use `-e` flag for perl to execute. Then pass the shell variable to perl script by using argument method. Then handle the value inside the perl using `$ARGV[0]`

```
echo "I M IN KSH"
i=10
echo "value of i in ksh is $i"
perl -e '

print "I M IN PERL\n";
use Time::Local;

my $i = $ARGV[0];
print "Value of i in perl $i\n";
$time_epoo = timegm(13,06,22,29,2,2016-1900);

print "$time_epoo"

'   $i

echo "BACK IN KSH"
```